# Are Android compose screen animation Transition only possible when using Compose Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-transitions

My current android application employs Jetpack Compose for its UI
I would like to add screen transition animations however i do not wish to use compose navigation.

I cannot find any documentation that details how to achieve screen transition animations
that does not mention compose navigation

is it possible to implement screen transition animations without using compose navigation?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you choose for your "screens" and how you "navigate" between them - you'd need to choose how you do that first to figure out what types of transitions are supported with your chosen implementation. There's a [lot of animation APIs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation).

Comment: We are using multiple activities, each with their own compose screen components